# How to run PlistBuddy

Tags: macos, terminal, plist

I read here https://medium.com/@marksiu/what-is-plistbuddy-76cb4f0c262d

that PlistBuddy is in `usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`. But it is not there or at least I can't find it. Do you have to install something to get this ? I have xcode 12.5.1 installed with command line tools on my Mac.

[[image: Terminal Output1]

Text version:

```
$ ls -l /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  159728 Jan  1  2020 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
$ cd /usr/libexec
$ PlistBuddy
zsh: command not found: PlistBuddy
```

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? If in **Terminal** you run the following _command_ does it return anything? `ls -l /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`

Comment: Please see screenshot

Comment: screenshots can't be read - if it is text then show the text as text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PlistBuddy` is there as shown by the *output* in the screenshot of **Terminal** in your question:

```
ls -l /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  159728 Jan  1  2020 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
```

The problem is that `/usr/libexec/` is not in the `path` or `PATH` passed to the *shell* and once you `cd` into a *directory* that is not within the `path` or `PATH` passed to the *shell* you need to preface the *command* with `./`, e.g.,:

```
./PlistBuddy
```

Or just use it's *fully qualified pathname*, e.g.,:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
```

---

From a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** 11.5.2:

```
 % ls -l /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  159728 Jan  1  2020 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
 % echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
 % cd /usr/libexec/           
 % PlistBuddy               
zsh: command not found: PlistBuddy
 % ./PlistBuddy                 
Usage: PlistBuddy [-cxh] <file.plist>
    -c "<command>" execute command, otherwise run in interactive mode
    -x output will be in the form of an xml plist where appropriate
    -h print the complete help info, with command guide
 %
```